# Is [go where] in "The bus goes where most off-campus students live now." an abbreviation of usage?

Tags: wh-questions

I read this sentence.

> "The bus goes where most off-campus students live now."

Is it the same as

> "The bus goes (to some place) where most off-campus students live now"?

or

> "The bus goes (some place) where most off-campus students live now"?

Is [go where] an usual expression?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with **go where** - "I must go where my husband goes, and he must go where jobs in his field are to be found." However, your sentence sounds odd without the name of the district, or some reference to its location, being mentioned.

Comment: The first sounds like perfectly natural speech to me. I'm surprised anyone would complain about it. FWIW, I'm a middle-aged American.

Comment: I knew [go where] is okay. But I just wonder about any explanation for detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, your first example is not idiomatic.

To say: **The bus goes where.....** doesn't work in that context.

As in your second example, you have to say something like:
**The bus goes to areas/suburbs/locations where people live.**

However, it's possible to construct sentences such as:

**The bus goes where and when the driver chooses.**
and
**The bus goes wherever passengers wish.**

Here the context and intention are different.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "the bus goes where..." is not idiomatic.  You acknowledge that "The bus goes *where the driver chooses*" is fine, so why can't it be "where most students live"?

Comment: @stangdon I don't think that the construction is ungrammatical. I do think that it doesn't sound natural. I note that others may disagree.

Comment: The first sentence is perfectly idiomatic to my Canadian ear

Comment: It seems to me that it is possible to construct any number of similar sentences, the meaning of which can be understood, but which grate on the colloquial ear; I don't think that there is a rule that permits or excludes them all. Consider: The soldiers aimed where the people were gathered. The swimmers preferred where the water was calm. The president arrived where his supporters waited. I find these constructions awkward, while The bus goes where the driver wishes is fine.